# Pegando elementos de tabela com htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Tenho essa estrutura repedida várias vezes.

**1º Tabela**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>titulo</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**2ª Tabela**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Texto</th>
<th>Texto</th>
<th>Texto</th>
<th>Texto</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

São várias seguindo esse padrão.

Como faço para passar elas para um array e uma lista para eu pegar os valores de cada ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta. Você quer passar esse o conteúdo que esta dentro do elemento TH para uma lista ? É isso ? Você tem uma ou mais tabelas no seu html ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma ferramenta auxilar ao **HtmlAgility** que seria o `Fizzler`!! 
ele tem a mesma finalidade do **HtmlAgility** porem nele você pode fazer "query's" no seu objeto para pegar o elemento desejado, 
você pode baixar o Fizzler no nuget mesmo,

e funcionaria assim

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36");
string pag = wc.DownloadString("pagina de onde você quer pegar a informação");
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml2(pag);
var tabela = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tags do queryselector").ToList();
```

você pode pesquisar um pouco mais sobre as tags do queryselector mais o basico seria

"#" = ID do elemento,

"." = classe do elemento,

e as tags do s elementos em html normalmente!